# convert to date and extract only the time

Tags: plsql

How could I get only time of a varchar2? I do:

```
  select to_date(substr(fecha,10,16),'HH:MI:SS AM') from total;
```

But it gives me:

```
01/06/2014 5:50:01
01/06/2014 5:50:05
01/06/2014 5:50:05
01/06/2014 5:50:50
```

And I would like to have:

```
5:50:01
5:50:05
5:50:05
5:50:50
```

Any help? Please

Comment: try this `SELECT to_char(fetcha, 'HH24:MI:SS')
  FROM table`

Comment: dont works. Fecha is varchar. I would like to convert to date to then make comparaisons. It says me number not valid

Answer (score 1):

Although it may not be what you expected, the code is working correctly. In Oracle, if you don't specify the day-month-year portion of a date it defaults to the first day of the current month. An Oracle DATE must always have a day/month/year - there's no way to have a time without a date in a DATE column or variable.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c149/2).

If you really want to have it display only the time portion of the date you'll just have to extract only the hours-minutes-seconds using `TO_CHAR(date_value, 'HH24:MI:SS')` and treat it as a character string.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use both, to_char and to_date:

```
select to_char(to_date(fecha,'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MI:SS AM'),'HH:MI:SS AM') 
time from total;
```

Comment: I agree with your general approach, yet it is not apparent that 'dd-mm-yyyy' is in the varchar2, fecha.  If 'dd-mm-yyyy' is not in fecha (e.g. only time is), then this will not work.